# Split PDF and add Password in PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, split, itext

I want to split PDF file and add password to protect them.
I can split PDF but I can't add password for each split file.
From my code I found error "java.io.IOException: PDF header signature not found."
I don't know to solve them :'(

`

```
public class TestSplitPDF {

private static String USER_PASS = "Hello123";

private static String OWNER_PASS = "12345";


public void createPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException {

        OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);         
        Document document = new Document();         
        PdfCopy c = new PdfCopy(document,new FileOutputStream(filename));
                    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
                    pdfWriter.setEncryption(USER_PASS.getBytes(), OWNER_PASS.getBytes(),
                            PdfWriter.AllowPrinting, PdfWriter.STRENGTH128BITS);
                    document = new Document();
                    document.open();
                    int pageSize = reader.getNumberOfPages();
                    System.out.println(filename +" Page : "+pageSize);
                    for (int i=1 ; i<pageSize ; i++) {
                        c.addPage(c.getImportedPage(reader, i));
                    }
                    document.close();
                    file.close();
                    //reader.close();

}

public void SplitPDF () {
      try {
          PdfReader Split_PDF_By_Size = new PdfReader("C:/JavaCode/PDFTest.pdf");          
          Document document=new Document();
          PdfCopy copy=new PdfCopy(document,new FileOutputStream("C:/JavaCode/PDFTest_1.pdf"));
          document.open();          
          int number_of_pages = Split_PDF_By_Size.getNumberOfPages();
          int pagenumber=1; /* To generate file name dynamically */
          int Find_PDF_Size; /* To get PDF size in bytes */
          float combinedsize=0; /* To convert this to Kilobytes and estimate new PDF size */ 
          String FileName = "C:/JavaCode/PDFTest_1.pdf";
          for (int i = 1; i < number_of_pages; i++ ) {
              if (combinedsize==0 && i !=1 ){ /* Generate new file only for second time when first document size
                          exceeds limit and incoming loop counter is not 1 */
                  document = new Document();
                  pagenumber++;
                  FileName="C:/JavaCode/PDFTest_"+ pagenumber+".pdf"; /* Dynamic file name */                    
                  copy = new PdfCopy(document,new FileOutputStream(FileName));
                  document.open();
                  copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(Split_PDF_By_Size, i)); /* Import pages from original document */
                  Find_PDF_Size=copy.getCurrentDocumentSize(); /* Estimate PDF size in bytes */           
                  combinedsize=(float)Find_PDF_Size/1024; /* Convert bytes to kilobytes */  
                  }//end if
              else {
                  copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(Split_PDF_By_Size, i)); /* Import pages from original document */
                  Find_PDF_Size=copy.getCurrentDocumentSize(); /* Estimate PDF size in bytes */           
                  combinedsize=(float)Find_PDF_Size/1024; /* Convert bytes to kilobytes */  
              }
                  if (combinedsize > 1024 || i==number_of_pages) { /* Close document if the page is the last page or if limit reaches */
                  document.close();
                  combinedsize=0; /* reset variable to generate next file, if required */
                  }//end if
          }//end for
          document.close();
          System.out.println("PDF Split By Size Completed. Number of Documents Created:"+pagenumber);  
          for(int p=1 ; p<pagenumber ; p++) {
         FileName = "C:/JavaCode/PDFTest_"+p+".pdf";
        TestSplitPDF pdf2 = new TestSplitPDF();
        pdf2.createPdf(FileName);
          }//end for     
        }//end try
        catch (Exception i)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }//end catch      
}//end splitPDF
public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    TestSplitPDF usePDF = new TestSplitPDF();
    usePDF.SplitPDF();
}



   }
```

`

Thank you for help.

Comment: Have the _split_ documents been saved before trying to add password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The moment you create the `file` object, you destroy the PDF you were about to read (it turns into an open file with 0 bytes):

```
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
```

Then when you try reading this file, you get an `IOException`:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
```

PDF header signature not found. This means that `PdfReader` doesn't find `%PDF-` at the start of the file. It's obvious why this happens: the file is no longer a PDF file, it's a file with 0 bytes.

This is how you should fix your method:

```
public void createPdf(String src, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    stamper.setEncryption(USER_PASS.getBytes(), OWNER_PASS.getBytes(),
                        PdfWriter.AllowPrinting, PdfWriter.STRENGTH128BITS);
    stamper.close();
}
```

Your code was really difficult to read: you're mixing `PdfCopy` and `PdfWriter`. Please read the documentation before you start coding and don't start coding with a version of iText that refers to my name (I'm Lowagie and you're using `com.lowagie` classes). Read this page for more info: http://itextpdf.com/salesfaq

Comment: Thank you for your explanation about this library so I will learn from document and do it best.

Comment: @OkumuraAyaka *explanation about this library* - well, your issue was not really iText specific, and neither is the fix. Instead it was about understanding Java IO.